# Ubuntu 15.10 login loop for all users

Tags: unity, lightdm, 15.10

On a previously working install of Ubuntu 15.10, I rebooted and am now unable to log in to Unity with any users (main account or guest). I can log into my shell in another tty.

I've tried all the suggested fixes in the [highest-voted question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop?lq=1) on this subject, to no avail.

My `.xsession-errors` looks suspicious:

`openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: upstart-event-bridge main process (5926) terminated with status 1
upstart: upstart-event-bridge main process ended, respawning
... (last two logs repeated)
upstart: upstart-event-bridge respawning too fast, stopped
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (3123) terminated with status 1`

This leads me to Ubuntu bug [1432317](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1432317), which doesn't seem to have a resolution.

Any suggestions for other diags to check? Here are some things I've tried:

- Per https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/39801, Permissions on `.Xauthority`, `.ICEauthority`, and `tmp` are correct.
- I've tried removing `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.config/compiz-1`.
- Moving mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.old
- Restarting/reinstalling lightdm and ubuntu-desktop doesn't help
- Installing gnome-session-flashback doesn't fix the issue
- Newly created users are affected by the issue
- I have plenty of free space on all my mounts.

In case it's relevant, I'm running Ubuntu as a VM under Parallels 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this issue by rolling back to a previous kernel version, and deleting the one that was giving me problems. Not a satisfactory answer, but I'll leave it here since I didn't spot that suggestion in other instances of this issue.